# Emoji character outline in SVG

Tags: html, css, image, svg, emoji

I'm trying to create an outline of an emoji character (meaning I want to draw just the outer shape of the emoji) in SVG. The best I could come up with so far is to use two masked rectangles, scaled and super-imposed on each other.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="100">  
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter">
      <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 1 0" />
    </filter>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100">  
      <text filter="url(#filter)" x="0" y="80" font-family="Helvetica" font-weight="bold" font-size="7em" fill="#000000"></text>
    </mask>  
  </defs>
  <path fill="#fff" d="M0 0 L0 100 L100 100 L100 0z"/>
  <path fill="#000000" d="M0 0 L0 100 L100 100 L100 0z" mask="url(#mask)"/>
  <g transform="translate(5, 5) scale(0.9)">
    <path d="M0 0 L100 0 L100 100 L0 100z" mask="url(#mask)" fill="#fff"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Depending on the particular emoji the result isn't very satisfactory though because not all emojis fill width and height equally.

[image: rendered SVG]

Is there a better way to achieve an outline effect for emoji characters?

Comment: This might not be what you’re looking for, but OpenMoji offers all their emojis as black/white SVGs, too: https://openmoji.org/library/ (CC BY-SA 4.0 license)

Comment: @Boldewyn Neat! This is actually sufficient for my needs. I'm merely using the emojis for success / failure states on https://johennes.github.io/senor-123/ and the OpenMoji SVGs were super easy to integrate. Thanks a lot for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need a viewBox for the svg element and I am using  viewBox="0 -30 157 140" slightly bigger than the bounding box of the text element.
2. instead of a mask I'm using clipPath to clip a white rectangle
3. The filter I'm using is feMorphology operator="dilate" and I'm applying the filter to a group wrapping the clipped rectangle.

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" viewBox="0 -30 157 140">
<defs>
<filter id="outline-indigo">
<feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" result="expanded"
operator="dilate" radius="3"/>
<feFlood flood-color="indigo" result="indi" />
<feComposite in ="indi" in2="expanded" operator="in" />
<feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>

<clipPath id='emojiClipPath'> 
      <text filter="url(#filter)" x="0" y="80" font-family="Helvetica" font-weight="bold" font-size="7em" fill="#000000"></text>
</clipPath>
</defs>
  
<g filter="url(#outline-indigo)">
  <rect y="-30" width="157" height="140" fill="white" clip-path='url(#emojiClipPath)'/>
</g>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Impressive! I hadn't thought of such a filter combo. Thanks a lot!